# Raise I/O error while writing to an unreliable disk in C++

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling, disk-io

Imagine you have the following in C++:

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open (argv[1]);

if (myfile.is_open()){
 for(int n=0;n<=10;n++){
     myfile << "index="<<n<<endl;
     sleep(1);
 }
}else{
cerr << "Unable to open file";
}

myfile.close();
```

And while writing, the disk or medium you are writing to becomes unavailable but comes back on for the `close()` so that you have missing data in between. Or imagine you write to a USB flash drive and the device is withdrawn and re-inserted during the writing process.

How can you detect that ? I tried checking putting the write in `try {} catch`, `flags()`, `rdstate()`, you name it, but none thus far seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is something you can detect at the stdio level.  Typically when a hard drive temporarily stops responding, the operating system will automatically retry the commands either until they succeed or a timeout is reached, at which point your system call may receive an error.  (OTOH it may not, because your call may have returned already, after the data was written into the in-memory filesystem cache but before any commands were sent to the actual disk)

If you really want to detect flakey hard drive, you'll probably need to code to a much lower level, e.g. write your own hardware driver.

Comment: How about when I write to a USB flash drive and the device is withdrawn during the writing process ?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you can try to:

1. Use [ios:exceptions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/exceptions/)
2. Use low-level OS interactions
3. Verify that IO was successful (if 1 and 2 doesn't work)

Comment: 1: Tried, see my comment to Eric's answer 
2-3: Like what for example ?

Comment: @madreblu, 2 is OS specific, you should dive in documentation. 3 - try to read what you've write and verify that it's matches. You can use some checksum or hash algorithm like MD5, SHA or CRC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will cover your scenario (removing a USB drive mid-write), but you can try enabling exceptions on the stream:

```
myfile.exceptions(ios::failbit | ios::badbit);
```

In my experience, iostreams do a "great" job of making it hard to detect errors and the type of error.

Comment: He says he's checking rdstate, which would triggers on the same things as those exceptions, so those exceptions wouldn't be firing.

Comment: The code is this now but still says rdstate is goodbit :  myfile.exceptions ( ofstream::failbit | ofstream::badbit );

    myfile.open (argv[1]);
    if (myfile.is_open()){
 for(int n=0;n<=10;n++){
     cout << "index="<<n<<endl;
     try{
          cout << "index="<<n<<endl;
          myfile << "index="<<n<<endl;
         }catch (exception e) {
          cerr << "Fail to write "<<e.what();
          return 1;
         }
     myfile<<flush;
         sleep(1);
     }
    }else{
 cerr << "Unable to open file";
 return 1;
    }  
    cout<<(myfile.rdstate()==ios::goodbit)<<endl;

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int n=0;n<=10;n++){
    if (!(myfile << "index="<<n<<endl))
        throw std::runtime_error("WRITE FAILED")
    sleep(1);
}
```

If the `std::ostream` fails for any reason, it sets it's state bit, which is checked then the `std::stream` is in a boolean context.  This is the same way you check if an `std::istream` read in data to a variable correctly.

However, this is the same as `rdstate()`, which you say you tried.  If that's the case, the write has gotten to a buffer.  `endl`, which flushes the programs buffer, shows that it's in the Operating System's buffer.  From there, you'll have to use OS-specific calls to force it to flush the buffer.

[Edit] According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17618685(v=VS.100).aspx, you can force a flush with `_commit` if you have a file descriptor.  I can't find such a guarantee for `std::ostream`s.

Comment: I wrote but nothing was raised: 
     if (!(myfile << "index="<<n<<endl)){
  cerr << "Fail to write "<<endl;;
  return 1;
     }
     myfile<<flush;

Comment: @madreblu: That means the file is in the OS memory, _outside_ of your program.  I'm still trying to figure out how to force a flush, other than filling RAM.  What's your target OS?  Or are you aiming for portable?

Comment: I wrote "myfile<<flush;" still does not work, I am with Linux all the way :-)

Comment: @madreblu: Try calling `std::ostream::pubsync()` and see if that works.  It might, but I doubt it.

Comment: @madreblu: for Linux: does your stream have `fstream::filedesc()` or `fstream::rdbuf()->fd()` members?  If so, call `_commit(...)` on them, that _might_ do it.  Or if you have a `fstream::sync()` that might work too.